# How to pass data through redirect()

Tags: laravel

I've made a form that uses `Route::delete();` to delete a user (which works), however I am struggling to pass a success messages that says 'User deleted successfully'.

After `$user->delete();` I call `return redirect('dashboard/users/list')->with('success', 'User deleted successfully.');`, but this returns an error similar to '$success is not set' when calling it in blade.

Is there a way to pass messages through a redirect instead of just calling the view?

Comment: what do you mean by `but this does not work.` ..

Comment: @aswzen edited question

Comment: how do you access the flashed values in the view?

Comment: @ab_ab using `{{ $success }}`

Comment: use `{{ Session::get('success') }}`. read laravel doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to pass data thru redirect is only using parameter,

`return redirect('dashboard/users/list')->with('success', 'User deleted successfully.');`

and in show() read it with

`{{ Session::get('success') }}`